# How to know the information of USB endpoints?

Tags: usb, hardware, hardware-interface

How can I determine the number and type of endpoints(control - IN/OUT,interrupt-IN/OUT?) my USB device is having.DOes it differs if I plug the same device onto different hosts(Linux,Windows,Mac)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [libusb](http://libusb.info/).  It runs on all of those platforms and it has functions for retrieving the configuration descriptor from the device.  You could then parse the configuration descriptor to figure out how many endpoints there are.

Or you could just run `lsusb -v`, which will show you tons of information about your device.